Having problems with pulseaudio
My Laptop has no audio output with either plug-in headphone or build-in speakers. Bluetooth headphones work. Settings recognize build-in Speakers and AUX Headphone, but Pulseaudio Volumecontrol sometimes says Speakers (unavailable) and I couldn't find out why that is yet.
I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad L14 Gen 1 with Ubuntu version 22.04.4 LTS.
On the pulseaudio Volumecontrol it reads audio reaching the channel when I play audio, as does the settings menu, but I hear silence. Here are a few commands I've seen help people identify problems on other posts, but to be honest I don't know what some of them or their output exactly mean. I Hope they help somehow, I'm happy to run and post other commands that may help to figure this out.
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor >
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-08-13 01:37:13 CEST; 2 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 449676 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18835)
     Memory: 8.0M
        CPU: 3min 40.702s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulsea>
             └─449676 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Aug 15 19:50:07 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Capture': >
Aug 15 19:50:08 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Capture': >
Aug 15 19:50:08 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Capture': >
Aug 15 19:50:13 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Headphone'>
Aug 15 19:52:19 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Headphone'>
Aug 15 19:53:56 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Battery Level: 100%
Aug 15 19:55:10 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Headphone'>
Aug 15 19:55:45 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set volume of 'Internal M>
Aug 15 19:55:45 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set switch of 'Capture': >
Aug 15 19:55:50 swagpad pulseaudio[449676]: Failed to set volume of 'Speaker': >

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 4 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [17aa:507c]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller [8086:02a3]

$ aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ pacmd list-cards
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1438000 irq 148"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.product.name = "Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 32833, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 39268, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 39333, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 38668, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 38733, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#4: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#8: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 2
    name: <bluez_card.98_67_2E_A2_7A_11>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        device.description = "Indy Evo"
        device.string = "98:67:2E:A2:7A:11"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_98_67_2E_A2_7A_11"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "Indy Evo"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
        bluetooth.battery = "100%"
        bluetooth.codec = "mSBC"
    profiles:
        handsfree_head_unit: Handsfree Head Unit (HFP) (priority 30, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <handsfree_head_unit>
    sinks:
        bluez_sink.98_67_2E_A2_7A_11.handsfree_head_unit/#3: Indy Evo
    sources:
        bluez_sink.98_67_2E_A2_7A_11.handsfree_head_unit.monitor/#5: Monitor of Indy Evo
        bluez_source.98_67_2E_A2_7A_11.handsfree_head_unit/#6: Indy Evo
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

I've tried killing the pulseaudio daemon and restarting it, -v and -vvvvv, uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio, renaming the file /home/.config/pulse to old_pulse so it gets renewed on startup.
At some point something went wrong with gdm3 and my desktop manager switched to lightdm, which I downloaded before to give it a try and still had installed. I thought that that should narrow it down to something wrong with my userspace and not a systemwide problem, but I don't know if I understood the other post correctly on that.
I really don't know what to do, it would be really helpful if someone could help me take a look at this.
Thanks in advance, Kangev!

Did you try alsamixer to see that the audio was not muted? and do you have pavucontrol? with that you can choose different configurationSudo apt install pavucontrol

Yeah, alsamixer shows that it's not muted. I have pavucontrol and I see the bar moving when audio plays, but there is no output to my headphones.
